# ¿Cómo mostrar en pantalla lo que se esta escribiendo en un Input mientras lo escribimos con Javasscript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, eventos

Estoy tratando de mostrar en pantalla lo que el usuario va escribiendo en un Input, pero no encuentro como hacerlo.

Intente con el evento `change` pero solo nota el cambio cuando se quita el focus del input.

También intente con el evento `keypress` pero este va un caracter atrasado, o sea si en el input escribo: `123` donde estoy mostrando lo que se escribe aparece así `12`

Gracias!

Comment: Pon tu código, y a partir de ahí es mas fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes valerte del [evento `onkeyup`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp), que se dispara cuando el usuario *suelta* una tecla sobre el input. Para entonces, este elemento tiene ya el texto que esa tecla haya podido añadir o eliminar.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = `
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="texto">Texto</label>
    <input id="texto" />
  </div>
  <div id="copia"></div>
</form>
`;

let txtInput = document.querySelector('#texto');
let divCopia = document.getElementById('copia');

txtInput.addEventListener('keyup',()=>{
    divCopia.innerHTML = txtInput.value;
});
```